# Basic recursion with if else statement (java)

Tags: java, recursion

Reviewing my notes and was wondering if anyone has a concise explanation for what is occurring below:

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[]args){
    helloWorld(10);

}

public static void helloWorld(int n){
      if(n > 0){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld! " + n);
        helloWorld(n-1);
        }
        System.out.println("GoodBye from " + n);
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld! 10
HelloWorld! 9
HelloWorld! 8
HelloWorld! 7
HelloWorld! 6
HelloWorld! 5
HelloWorld! 4
HelloWorld! 3
HelloWorld! 2
HelloWorld! 1
GoodBye from 0
GoodBye from 1
GoodBye from 2
GoodBye from 3
GoodBye from 4
GoodBye from 5
GoodBye from 6
GoodBye from 7
GoodBye from 8
GoodBye from 9
GoodBye from 10
```

Just to be clear, I totally understand what's happening above with the recursion and the call stack unwinding. My question is about what happens when I include an else statement below:

```
public static void helloWorld(int n){

    if(n > 0){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld! " + n);
        helloWorld(n-1);

        }else{
        System.out.println("GoodBye from " + n);

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld! 10
HelloWorld! 9
HelloWorld! 8
HelloWorld! 7
HelloWorld! 6
HelloWorld! 5
HelloWorld! 4
HelloWorld! 3
HelloWorld! 2
HelloWorld! 1
GoodBye from 0
```

Why does the call stack appear to not unwind when it hits the else statement?

Comment: Why would Goodbye 1-10 get printed if that only happens when n is 0 (or less)?

Comment: When it enters in `if` statement, Why do you expect it to execute else statement as well?

Comment: 0 is only reached once, hence only once the else branch is executed. The stack unwinding happens 11 times in both versions, only without `else` 10 extra prints are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call stack unwinds in both cases. It just doesn't print anything when it unwinds in the second snippet, since you only print `"GoodBye from " + n` when `n` is 0, which happens exactly once.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd case the else block will be executed only for `n = 0` as it is going in the if block. However in the first case, after each recursion completes `System.out.println("GoodBye from " + n);` will be executed as it is not bound with any condition.